# Mysql: Encrypt old data in database

Tags: mysql, encryption, aes

I have small problem with mysql. I have data in table and I want to encrypt them. I use this commands:

```
UPDATE `Name_Table` SET `COL1`=(SELECT AES_ENCRYPT( `COL1`, 'difficultKey')) WHERE 1
```

and

```
UPDATE `Name_Table` SET `COL1`=AES_ENCRYPT( `COL1`, 'difficultKey') WHERE 1
```

But this commend destroy my data (I can't decrypt). Can you help me?

I use to this:
- phpmyadmin (bookmark - sql)
- utf8_general to comparing strings

Please, can you help me?

Comment: What do you need to encrypt the data for?

Comment: If you want to hide user passwords you should use hashing instead of encryption.

Comment: We need encrypt adress email and another important data for client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that the data type of your column is "varchar/char". That's why the data is getting destroyed. Apparently you should store anything that is to be AES_ENCRYPTed in blob format

I think it is because a varchar field can't handle certain characters that are produced from the encryption.

Quoting the MYSQL documentation for [AES_ENCRYPT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-decrypt).

" AES_ENCRYPT() encrypts a string and returns a binary string"

Therefore, you'd need a BLOB (Binary Large object).

Comment: I understand that to decrypt i can give BLOB ? `SELECT AES_DECRYPT( COLofBLOB , 'difficultKey' ) FROM Name_table`? The last questions: If I encrypt all data in table how I can search using where? I can use: `((...) WHERE col = AES_DECRYPT(col,'KEY'))` ?